# Shakespeare's “say sooth” vs. “tell truth”

Tags: meaning, differences, archaicisms, old-english, shakespeare

The noun *[**sooth**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sooth)*, pronounced /suːθ/, is now archaic and means ‘fact’,‘reality’ and ‘truth’. Its legacy persists in the words *[soothe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/soothe)* /suːð/, and *[soothsayer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/soothsayer)* meaning someone who sees the truth, a synonym of *fortune teller* and the French loanword *clairvoyant*.

In Shakespeare's plays, *sooth* is often used with the verb *say* and in the expression *in sooth* whereas *truth* is often used with the verb *tell*

From Shakespeare's *Macbeth*

> > **Sergeant**:
> >     If I **say sooth**, I must report they were
> >     As cannons overcharged with double cracks, so they
> >     Doubly redoubled strokes upon the foe:

(Act I, Scene 2)

> > **Banquo**:
> >     And oftentimes, to win us to our harm,
> >     The instruments of darkness **tell us truths**,
> >     Win us with honest trifles, to betray’s
> >     In deepest consequence.

(Act I, Scene 3)

> > **Macbeth**:
> >     [Aside] Two **truths are told**,
> >     As happy prologues to the swelling act
> >     Of the imperial theme.—I thank you, gentlemen.

(Act I, Scene 3)

> > **Macbeth**:
> >     If thou speak'st false,
> >     Upon the next tree shalt thou hang alive,
> >     Till famine cling thee: if thy speech be **sooth**,
> >     I care not if thou dost for me as much.
> >     I pull in resolution, and begin
> >     To doubt the equivocation of the fiend
> >     That lies like **truth**: 'Fear not, till Birnam wood
> >     Do come to Dunsinane:'…

(Act V, Scene 5)

*Merchant of Venice*

> > **Antonio**:
> >     **In sooth**, I know not why I am so sad:
> >     It wearies me; you say it wearies you;

(Act I, Scene 1)

Etymonline tells me that **[*truth*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/truth#etymonline_v_17903)** meaning "something that is true" was first recorded in the mid-14 century. In the 1560s, *truth* came to mean "accuracy, correctness". Meanwhile, the noun *sooth* is dated 900 and was derived from *soð*.

- I would like to know what difference in meaning, if any, was there between *sooth* and *truth*?
- Why did “sooth” become obsolete, and when was it eventually overtaken by “truth”?

Comment: I've never thought about it before but looking at the examples you give it looks to me as though Will used _sooth_ for something that was communicated (in other words _say sooth_ meant _to tell the truth_) whereas a _truth_ meant something that was true independently of the communication (for example it is _true_ that the sun rises in the east). Would you agree?

Comment: @BoldBen it could be... the Bard frequently uses "sooth" with the verb "say" e.g. *And* ***tell thy king*** *I do not seek him now; /
But could be willing to march on to Calais /
Without impeachment: for,* **to say the sooth**, / (History of Henry V, Act III, Scene 6)

Comment: Before  Shakespeare it was used also by Chaucer in  “The Canterbury Tales” :,  second half  of 15th century - 595/610, “*As wyves mooten, for it is usage-. And with my coverchief covered my visage;. But for that I was ... He was, I trowe, a twenty wynter oold,. And I was fourty, **if I shal seye sooth,.** But yet I hadde alwey a coltes ...*” http://www.librarius.com/canttran/wifetale/wifetale593-632.htm

Comment: I've no idea why *sooth* died out of use, and I suggest Shakespeare used *say sooth* and *tell truth* because he knew better than most both that alliteration is the strongest trick in the English writer's tool-kit and that variety is the spice of speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-soo1.htm) appears to suggest that ther is no real difference in meaning between sooth and truth:

> ***Sooth does indeed mean “truth”,*** an Old English word. It has not been in daily use for about four centuries, except in the phrases by my sooth or my sooth, interjections now obsolete which emphasised that the speaker was telling the truth.

Regarding your second question, it appears the term was commonly used till mid 1600s and has been considered archaic   since then.

***[Sooth](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sooth):***

> Archaic in English, it is the root of modern words for "true" in Swedish (sann) and Danish (sand). ***In common use until mid-17c.***, then obsolete until ***revived as an archaism early 19c***. by Scott, etc. Used for Latin pro- in translating compounds into Old English, e.g. soðtacen "prodigy," soðfylgan "prosequi."

(Etymonline)

> Sooth was reintroduced in the nineteenth century as a literary archaism by writers such as Sir Walter Scott.
>
> - In sooth, there was that in her face and in her voice when she spoke which almost made Anne weep, through its strange sweetness and radiance.
>   (*A Lady of Quality, by Frances Hodgson Burnett, 1896. This work is exceptionally full of sooth — the author uses the word 20 times.*)

Answer (score 3):

Etymonline says [sooth](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sooth#etymonline_v_23888) -- born with the English language itself -- was in use till mid 17th century, but it doesn't directly explain its demise. (I liked the bit about it being connected to sin as in “being the one”, which makes sin a relative of the modern day German verb 'to be', *sein*).

It seems there must have been a long phase where 'truth' and 'sooth' performed different functions. 'Truth', also around since Old English days, originally had the sense of being true as in demonstrating faithfulness and loyalty.

From [dictionary etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/truth#etymonline_v_17903)

> Old English triewð (West Saxon), treowð (Mercian) "faith,
>   faithfulness, fidelity, loyalty; veracity, quality of being true;
>   pledge, covenant," from Germanic abstract noun *treuwitho, from
>   Proto-Germanic treuwaz "having or characterized by good faith," from
>   PIE *drew-o-, a suffixed form of the root *deru- "be firm, solid,
>   steadfast." With Germanic abstract noun suffix *-itho (see -th (2)).

Until the mid 14th century 'sooth' alone would have covered the other uses 'truth' has today of expressing factuality.

> Old English soð "truth, justice, righteousness, rectitude; reality,
>   certainty," noun use of soð (adj.) "true, genuine, real; just,
>   righteous," originally *sonð-, from Proto-Germanic *santhaz (source
>   also of Old Norse sannr, Old Saxon soth, Old High German sand "true,"
>   Gothic sunja "truth").

But it would seem then that in the mid 14th century the meaning of truth expanded. (still etymology online)

> Sense of "something that is true" is first recorded mid-14c. Meaning
>   "accuracy, correctness" is from 1560s.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth), modern day English 'truth' is now alone amongst Germanic languages.

> All Germanic languages besides English have introduced a
>   terminological distinction between truth "fidelity" and truth
>   "factuality". To express "factuality", North Germanic opted for nouns
>   derived from sanna* "to assert, affirm", while continental West
>   Germanic (German and Dutch) opted for continuations of wâra "faith,
>   trust, pact" (cognate to Slavic věra "(religious) faith", but
>   influenced by Latin verus). Romance languages use terms following the
>   Latin veritas, while the Greek aletheia, Russian pravda and South
>   Slavic istina have separate etymological origins. 
> [*cognate with soð according to etymonline]

But it seems to me that it is not so much the case that English didn't “introduce a terminologicad distinction”, but rathermore that it discarded the one it had.

I'm afraid I didn't find a direct explanation as to why sooth fell out of use, but if wikipedia and the online etymology dictionary speak sooth then it seems that 'truth' elbowed its way into 'sooth' territory in the mid 14th century. It's pure conjecture, but perhaps this contributed to the demise of 'sooth' in mid 17th century; it seems natural enough to assume that since 'truth' covered sooth and more, then if one were to fall by the wayside it would be 'sooth'. Strewth!

Comment: Ahh, God's truth = strewth :)

Comment: It’s worth noting that Etymonline’s transcription of Old English frequently leaves out length marks: the OE form of _sooth_ was actually _sōð_ (or _sōþ_, depending on how you prefer to write the dental phoneme), not _soð_. It’s also worth noting that the North Germanic (=Scandinavian) words “derived from _sanna_ ‘to assert, affirm’” are of course the ones mentioned as cognates to _sooth_ in the Etymonline quote further up.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yes, I agree; in the meantime I've included that relationship to 'sanna'.

Answer (score -1):

I'm about 4 years late to the party, but I was just thinking about this the other day.  I was wondering if truth might not be a portmanteau between "troth" and "sooth".  "Troth" the way I understand it meant something like fidelity, but also one's good word, and one's personal, subjective truth.  To tell "troth" meant to speak one's understanding of a situation accurately, while a "sooth"sayer was unique in being able to discourse in universal truths.  If I'm right in my guess, "Truth" emerged to simplify the function of the two words, and Shakespeare, who regularly used all three, marks a convergence point.

There is no legitimate research involved in the forming of this conjecture beyond reading a bunch of Shakespeare recently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).